# If Maximum order value is above £X show Javascript Alert

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, orders, javascript, ajax

I would like to ask for some advice on how I could show a Javascript alert to customers if their current shopping cart value is above say £300.

I am using an excellent observer based module from [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-maximum-allowed-order-amount/) that allows me to set maximum order values via admin. However, on the from end of our site we are using Ajax to add to the shopping cart so I would need to modify the Observer.php file in order to throw an exception in the form of a Javascript alert because the page simply freezes when the order value reaches the limit.

So far I have tried to add a

```
Mage::throwException("Quantity cannot exceed the maximum cart value ".$formattedPrice->getSingleOrderTopAmount());
```

to the Observer.php file but it hasn't worked as intended, also should I use the Incoo Observer.php or create a new one inside the Ajax add to cart module?

Observer.php from Inchoo module

```
    <?php

    class Inchoo_MaxOrderAmount_Model_Observer
{
    private $_helper;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->_helper = Mage::helper('inchoo_maxorderamount');
    }

    /**
     * No single order can be placed over the amount of X
     */
    public function enforceSingleOrderLimit($observer)
    {
        if (!$this->_helper->isModuleEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        if ((float)$quote->getGrandTotal() > (float)$this->_helper->getSingleOrderTopAmount()) {

            $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($this->_helper->getSingleOrderTopAmount(), true, false);

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError(
                $this->_helper->__($this->_helper->getSingleOrderTopAmountMsg(), $formattedPrice));

            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
     * An email is sent to admins when an order over X total price is placed in order to investigate
     */
    public function pushOrderAmountNotification($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        if ((float)$order->getGrandTotal() < (float)$this->_helper->getOrderAmountNotification()) {
            return;
        }

        $storeId = $order->getStoreId();

        if (!$this->_helper->isModuleEnabled()) {
            return;
        }  

        try {
            $notifyToEmails = $this->_helper->getNotifyToEmails();

            if (empty($notifyToEmails)) {
                return;
            }

            $templateId = $this->_helper->getOrderAmountNotificationEmailTemplate($storeId);
            $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');            

            foreach ($notifyToEmails as $entry) {
                $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
                $emailInfo->addTo($entry['email'], $entry['name']);
                $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
            }

            $mailer->setSender(array(
                'name' => $this->_helper->getStoreEmailAddressSenderOption('general', 'name'),
                'email' => $this->_helper->getStoreEmailAddressSenderOption('general', 'email'),
            ));

            $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
            $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
            $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order' => $order,
            ));

            $mailer->send();


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is where would I add the function to use a Javascript alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Inchoo's observer.php and modify below code

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->_helper->__($this->_helper->getSingleOrderTopAmountMsg(), $formattedPrice));

Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
exit;
```

with your custom code to show alert box.

Comment: Adding an exit into any code is bad style. The code is untestable and finding bugs might be quite hard